# Toggle verticalFit on an open image?

Tags: magnific-popup

I need Magnific to open up the image with verticalFit = true to start.  The image is portrait aspect and needs to fit within the viewport.  But if the user clicks on the image, Magnific should turn verticalFit = false so that the image expands to full size so that the user can pan around and see details.

It seems like the easiest way to accomplish this would be to toggle verticalFit on/off each time the user clicks on the image.

HTML:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="magnific-popup.css">
<a class="image-popup-vertical-fit" href="path-to-some-full-sized-image"><img src="path-to-thumbnail-image"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.magnific-popup.min.js"></script>
```

Javascript to link the HTML anchor tag with Magnific via the class "image-popup-vertical-fit":

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.image-popup-vertical-fit').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        closeBtnInside: false,
        closeOnContentClick: false,
        image: {
            verticalFit: true
        }

    });
});
</script>
```

There is a [partial thread over on GitHub](https://github.com/dimsemenov/Magnific-Popup/issues/140) from a year ago by another user but it doesn't really explain how it's being done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Solution**

```
jQuery(document).on('click', '.mfp-img', function(){        
    var mfp = jQuery.magnificPopup.instance; // get instance
    mfp.st.image.verticalFit = !mfp.st.image.verticalFit; // toggle verticalFit on and off
    mfp.currItem.img.removeAttr('style'); // remove style attribute, to remove max-width if it was applied
    mfp.updateSize(); // force update of size
});
```

**Explanation**

Based on the links you provided (thank you, you set me in the right direction to solve this), I compiled and tested the above code. I'm basically setting a `live` click listener on the `mfp-img` class which contains the images inside the popup. Once clicked, the code toggles the verticalFit option between true and false for the whole popup. Note that you should have jQuery 1.7 or above for the `on` handler to work, otherwise, convert the `on` handler to a `live` handler if you're using jQuery lower than 1.7.

Note that you need to set the option below while initializing the popup otherwise the custom click handler coded above will not work:

```
navigateByImgClick: false
```

Comment: To improve the visual and user experience, I modify the cursor so that it displays the zoom in/out accordingly.

Add this line of code to the javascript just before mfp.updateSize();

`mfp.currItem.img.toggleClass('zoom');`  
Add required CSS to go with it:

`img.mfp-img {
  cursor: zoom-in;
}
img.mfp-img.zoom {
  cursor: zoom-out;
}`